# Cocoa NSTextField Autocompletion Doesn't Work Properly When @ Sign Triggers Autocompletion

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am having a problem with implementing autocompletion in an NSTextField. I want autocompletion to be triggered when the user types + or @. (I am autocompleting projects and contexts in the todo.txt format.)

The way I've coded it, it works exactly as intended when a user types +, but it behaves erratically when a user types @. The way I have it coded right now, my `- (NSArray *)textView:(NSTextView *)textView completions:(NSArray *)words forPartialWordRange:(NSRange)charRange indexOfSelectedItem:(int *)index` method doesn't return any autocompletion suggestions, because the `charRange` contains not just the @ sign but the word and space before the @ sign.

If I change how this method works, and don't try to match the `charRange` to my keywords, when @ triggers an autocompletion, the word and space prior to the @ sign is also replaced, when I just want the @ sign to be replaced.

I have subclassed NSTextField and implemented several methods to customize the built-in autocompletion functionality. I am returning a custom list of autocomplete suggestions. My code is below. I have read the Apple docs and Googled for days trying to figure this out. I think my approach may be wrong, and I'm willing to throw the hole thing out and start with a better approach.

My approach would work if I could fix the partial word range passed to the method that builds the autocompletion list. I know there is a `rangeForUserCompletion` method in the Text View object, but I have no idea how to make that work. Please help!

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface TETextField : NSTextField

@end

#define COMPLETION_DELAY (0.25)

@implementation TETextField

NSTimer *_completionTimer;

- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

- (NSArray *)textView:(NSTextView *)textView completions:(NSArray *)words forPartialWordRange:(NSRange)charRange indexOfSelectedItem:(int *)index

    // this will be defined elsewhere
    NSArray *keywords = @[@"@home", @"@work", @"@phone", @"+Report", @"+Presentation"];

    NSString *partialString = [[textView string] substringWithRange:charRange];
    NSLog(@"partialString: %@", partialString);

    NSMutableArray *matches = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSString *string in keywords) {
        if ([string rangeOfString:partialString
                          options:NSAnchoredSearch | NSCaseInsensitiveSearch
                            range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])].location != NSNotFound)
        {
            [matches addObject:string];
        }
    }

    [matches sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    return matches;
}

-(void)keyUp:(NSEvent *)event {
    if ([[event characters] isEqualToString:@"@"] || [[event characters] isEqualToString:@"+"]) {
        [self startCompletionTimer];
    } else {
        [self stopCompletionTimer];
    }
    [super keyUp:event];
}

- (void)doCompletion:(NSTimer *)timer {
    [self stopCompletionTimer];
    [self.currentEditor complete:self];
}

- (void)startCompletionTimer {
    [self stopCompletionTimer];
    _completionTimer = [NSTimer
                        scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:COMPLETION_DELAY target:self
                        selector:@selector(doCompletion:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void)stopCompletionTimer {
    [_completionTimer invalidate];
    _completionTimer = nil;
}

@end
```